# How to check if I run JavaScript code in a browser or not in a browser?

Tags: javascript

How to check if I run this code in a browser or not in a browser?
I have something like this

```
var x = 5;
if(/*inside a browser*/) document.write(x);  
else/*without a browser*/ console.log(x);
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "inside browser"?

Comment: Where else do you intend to run it from?

Comment: The console in Netbeans or a Browser like Chrome, Firefox and IE

Comment: I think you can check for existence of `window` object.

Comment: why even use document.write inside the browser anyway?

Comment: This question is in dire need of a little context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (typeof(window) != 'undefined') {
   //i am inside of browser environment
} else {
   //i am elsewhere (server?)
}
```

Comment: If `window` isn't declared, you'll throw a *ReferenceError*. You could do `if (this.window) {` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to detect node vs browser:

```
var inside_browser = (typeof module === 'undefined');
```

It will work if you are not defining module.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("Welcome, you have Javascript on.")
</script>

<noscript>JavaScript is off. Please enable to view full site.</noscript>
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is asking.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the intent. JavaScript can be run in non-browser environments, like a hosted scripting environment, the Rhino runtime, Node.js, etc. A low-level library might need to check where it is.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

A simpler solution than what is mentioned below is just calling `(this.window).`

Other answers have assumed you are asking about server (ex node.js) side JS vs in browser.  However, my initial idea was that you were asking about how to detect if something were run in a javascript console.  Here would be my method for that:

```
(function(){

    var _z = console;
    Object.defineProperty( window, "console", {
    get : function(){
        if( _z._commandLineAPI ){
        return true;
            }
        return false; 
    },
    set : function(val){
        _z = val;
    }
    });

})();
```

Modified for your purposes from [KSpace blog](http://kspace.in/blog/2013/02/22/disable-javascript-execution-from-console/).